# return plot and values from a function together

Tags: r, function, plot, ggplot2, lm

I have a function like this:

```
fun <- function(dataset){
  require(ggplot2)
  g <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_smooth(method = "lm") + geom_point()

l<-lm(y~x)
return (list(l, g))
    }
```

and I want to return both plot and the values, but it doesn't return the plot and I face this error:

> Error in .Call.graphics(C_palette2, .Call(C_palette2, NULL)) :
>   invalid graphics state

What can I do?

Comment: Please first provide a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that, it's quite hard to figure out the problem. I do see a typo though in the return statement (`g` instead of `p`), but this shouldn't be the main issue, I figure.

Comment: do you want the values to be on the plot?

Comment: It would be much better, but my question was about that print the values in the console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works, and you can get the plot. However, R warns that's not the way to do it.

```
fun <- function(dataset){
  require(ggplot2)
  p <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
       geom_smooth(method = "lm") + geom_point()

  l <- lm(y~x, data=dataset)
  return (list(l, p))
}

dataset <- data.frame(x= 1:10, y=1:10)
out <- fun(dataset)
```

Edit: I've had a look about the warning, it seems like something you can ignore. See link https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2016-December/073554.html

Comment: I tried and it returns this [[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = df[, 2] ~ df[, 1])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      df[, 1]  
  3.898e-16   -7.059e-01  


[[2]]
Error in .Call.graphics(C_palette2, .Call(C_palette2, NULL)) : 
  invalid graphics state

Comment: I did not draw the plot

Comment: To get plot, you need to type `out$p` at the command prompt. The function only _returns_ the plot.

Comment: I've tested the code I've given. It works. So, it seems something else is the matter.

Comment: No it did not unfortunately. it pasted it NULL for out$p

Comment: Sorry, actually the out[[2]] gives the plot.

To plot using `out$p` the return statement should be changed to `return (list(l=l, p=p))`. 
I've tested both.

Comment: The error messages you are getting is due to something else. Best to sort this out and put another question for those.

Comment: Great. You should hit the tick near my answer then.